# How can I trigger a gulp task with shell_exec()?

Tags: php, node.js, bash, deployment, gulp

I'm trying to set up a system that automatically pulls and compiles on a remote server when I push to a repository on GitHub. I've found a number of very useful things in getting this working, but I'm stuck with the last step: executing my task, `gulp --dist`.

I'm using [this excellent PHP script](https://github.com/vicenteguerra/git-deploy) to trigger the pull, which works great. I've forked that repository in order to try to add an additional option, `AFTER_PULL`, which executes a shell command after pulling finishes. [Here's my modification](https://github.com/JacobDB/git-deploy/blob/issue/2/deploy.php#L24-L30) (also below). In config.php, I'm setting the following:

```
define('AFTER_PULL', 'node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --dist');
```

That doesn't seem to ever fire, and no error seems to be triggered either.

I'm thinking it's probably a permissions thing, but the user (www-data) has permission to work in all the directories necessary. I found [this article detailing how to allow www-data to run without needing a password](http://www.davidkudera.com/2014/10/11/npm-without-sudo/), but after completing these steps, it's still not working.

I'm sure I must be doing something obviously wrong and I'm just unable to see it. The command works if I run it in a terminal with `sudo -Hu www-data`.

```
...

if (!empty(AFTER_PULL)) {
    try{
        shell_exec(AFTER_PULL);
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        fputs($file, $e . "\n");
    }
}

...
```

Comment: have you tried with full path to node binary?

Comment: I have not, will try now.

Comment: @Peter wow, I think that was it. I knew it was something silly. :) Thanks!

Comment: I will answer the question normally way please accept it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full path to node binary:

```
define('AFTER_PULL', ' /usr/bin/node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --dist');
```